# How to Trigger POST method of URL from TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, url, http-post

We are currently working with content database processes running over SQL Server 2008. To make a new feature for automation purposes we need to raise a POST method of an internal web application URL ( the app just get our code from team foundation and build projects on a remote server) from T-SQL code.

Is there any way to do that?

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Why does SQL Server need to post to a web site? Why don't you just have a queue table of some kind, and a background job that wakes up every minute using PowerShell or C# to check the queue table, and post to URLs when needed? SQL Server is not meant to be your general web/API pinger tool.

Comment: @Aaron - We have a set of database process steps already working. We just need a (automated) step that will be at the end of the current process to fire the POST action. That's all. We don't need or have external applications to have them observe a queue as well as cannot configure a time restriction to the POST be fired. We need it fired whenever all the previous steps were successful.

Comment: @G21 is this a server agent job?

Comment: Can you install a CLR object on the server?

Comment: @jcolebrand Thanks so much. I posted my own answer based on your suggestion! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jcolebrand: your approach to create a CLR stored procedure and make it available on the server to raise the POST method was the solution for my problem. Thanks.

Here is what I did:

1. Created the CLR stored procedure on VS over 3.5 net framework. To create this kind of projects go to **Add New Project...** > **Other Project Types** > **Database** and give a proper name.
2. Went to the database, set the database "***Owner***" property to "***sa***" user.
3. Set "***TRUSTWORTHY***" property to "***ON***" on the target database.
4. Deployed the CLR stored procedure with *PERMISSION LEVEL* : ***EXTERNAL***

Hope this answer helps others too. 
Don hesitate to contact me if you have questions.

Thanks all for responding!

Answer (score 0):

I have to say that I agree with the others on this one... create a CLR procedure, .NET code, PowerShell or something else that can be called.

**But if it has to come from T-SQL.**

You could (shuddering).. do and XP_CMDSHELL and then call CURL to do the post.

A good example is located [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/community/forums/thread/69200.aspx).

And if you need to format the curl command there are great resources out on the web such as this [one](https://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request).

Good luck on this one but please note on the [permissions and outright dangers of using of xp_cmdshell](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBAdmin/sql-server-and-xp_cmdshell-the)!!